# MONGODB updateOne() query issue

Tags: json, mongodb

This is for upateOne() query in mongodb..
According to me there are not any mistakes in the down given code but the error pops up saying:
" missing } after property list :"
The braces are fully intact, the colons are on and the commas are provided correctly..
Please if anyone could help me with this issue??

```
db.movieDetails.updateOne(
    {
    "title":"The Martian"
    },
    {
        $push : {
            "reviews":{
                $each : [
                {
                    "rating" : 0.5,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-12T07:00:00Z"),
                    "reviewer" : "Yabo A.",
                    "text"  : "reviewText2"
                },
                {
                    "rating" : 5,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-12T09:00:00Z"),
                    "reviewer" : "Kristina Z.",
                    "text" : "reviewText3"
                },
                {
                    "rating" : 2.5,
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-10-26T04:00:00Z"),
                    "reviewer" : "Matthew Samuel",
                    "text" : "reviewText4"
                },
                {
                    "rating" : 9.5,
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-11-23T04:00:00Z"),
                    "reviewer" : "Mahendra Singh Dhoni",
                    "text" : "reviewText5"
                },
                {
                    "rating" : 7.5,
                    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-27T09:00:00Z"),
                    "reviewer" : "Himesh Reshamiya",
                    "text" : "reviewText6"
                },
                {
                    "rating" : 8
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-10-26T04:00:00Z"),
                    "reviewer" : "Latish Malinga",
                    "text" : "reviewText7"
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the last document here you are missing a comma:

```
{
  "rating" : 8
  "date" : ISODate("2015-10-26T04:00:00Z"),
  "reviewer" : "Latish Malinga",
  "text" : "reviewText7"
}
```

Adding a comma after `8` will fix it.